# Will the app average rating change if I remove the apk that supports only Froyo or below?

Tags: google-play, rating

My app has 2 apks that support different versions of Android. They are both published on Play for a while. Now I'd like to remove one of them from the store. Would this affect the calculation of the average rating of my app?